# According to the Halacha, can I pray before brushing my teeth?

Tags: halacha, teeth

If I were at someone's house or with a large group of people where there is only one bathroom, can I pray Shahrit before brushing my teeth? I do not know where the quote is, but I know we are not allowed to pray if not presentable. Does the same apply to teeth? Are there any sources that specifically explain the cleanliness of teeth?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jack! This is an interesting question, as it is commonly understood that one ***must*** go to the bathroom before morning prayers and one ***may not*** engage in personal activities unnecessary for prayer. Brushing teeth may fall in the middle of those two as something not ***required*** for halachic cleanliness, but still conducive to, as you put it, presentability.

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna Brurah 4:9 writes "it is good to rinse out the mouth." [There are those who have the custom to rinse out their mouths before davening so their mouth is pure for prayer.]  So one can extend brushing ones teeth which today is the accepted method of cleaning one's mouth.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, can you by any chance put the quote?

Comment: Rinsing the mouth out with water is a VERY different prospect than brushing the teeth. Drinking a glass of water is considered permitted according to basically everybody, while brushing with a paste containing mint and sugar to make it tasty would certainly be more suspect. And the idea of "purity of mouth" as something discrete from "purity of body" seems pretty metaphorical.

Comment: I didn't think of that, @IsaacKotlicky

Comment: who said your drinking it many hold one can rinse out their mouth even on a fast day if they are very sensitve.so dont know where you are coming from

Comment: @sam it isn't a question of drinking anything - performing an unnecessary activity that gives personal pleasure would seem to be problematic (v'osi hishlachta acharei gei'echa) regardless of the activity.\

Comment: is the language "it is good to" the same in terms of force as a halachic requirement or sine qua non?